# Preamble for FS9800 Barcode Scanner

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, barcode, barcode-scanner

Does any one know how to set F6 to be a preamble on barcode scanner FS9800? The recommended keyboard configuration way is not working for us. The text editor display the message "F1-F10.....", but when using the arrow keys - nothing expected happens. May be some one has a code I can simply zip to force the setting?

Thanks.